# unable to redirect to external url from webapi

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

**webapi method:**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
  var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
     return response;
}
```

**ajax request**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/FaceBookIntegration/GET",
    type: "GET",   
    success: function (data, status,header, jqXHR) {

        alert("Local success callback.");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
        alert("Local error callback.");
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
        alert("Local completion callback.");
    }
});
```

here ajax call not coming into success block of ajax call.giving error no access is there any other way please suggest

Comment: Which Asp.net version are you using?

Comment: I guess it should be related to some Cross origin request problem. Can you check if you see any error in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work for you is because you are violating [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

By redirecting to another origin the browser sends the request to the origin you provided in the redirect and checks for Access-Control-* headers in the response. If there is no such headers or information in those headers do not match the request then the browser will block further processing of the response.